# How to do Spring context initialisation from a dependency library within a web application?

Tags: spring

I have a web application which uses Spring. Bean definitions and spring configuration for the web application are declared in **webapp-spring.xml**. This web application uses a library as its dependency. Let us say the library is called **data-access.jar**. This library is on the web application's classpath. The web application is configured to initialise spring context by the usual **web.xml** configuration:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath*:webapp-spring.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

The data-access.jar library also has its own spring beans xml definition **data-access-spring.xml** embedded within it (directly at the root level) for its internal use of Spring dependency injection.

When the web application context initialisation happens on starting the container (Tomcat), I would like Spring to initialise context using **data-access-spring.xml** along with **web-app-spring.xml**. How do I do this?

I tried following which didn't work:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath*:web-app-spring.xml,classpath*:data-access-spring.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Spring silently ignores data-access-spring.xml and only initialises the bean definitions from web-app-spring.xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`classpath*:` will basically ignore files which don't match the pattern. But your syntax is correct. So it looks like `data-access-spring.xml` isn't being found. Are you sure it's at the root?

You could also use patterns, btw, e.g. `classpath*:*-spring.xml`, but that shouldn't help you here. `classpath*:web-app-spring.xml,classpath*:**/data-access-spring.xml` might if it's not at the root.

Comment: The configuration I tried above is indeed correct. The issue was with the version of the data-access.jar being out of sync in the local maven repository from where the it was being added to web application classpath. I cleaned up the local repository (.m2) copy of the published data-access.jar, re-built and published/installed it and now both xml configurations are being picked up. Thanks.